# Wordpress blog in a subdomain of a Rails app - Downloading files and not rendering them

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, wordpress

I have a rails app hosted on www.figurella.com.do, and Right now the wordpress blog is hosted at blog.figurella.com.do everything seems fine, right?

Well if you go to blog.figurella.com.do/wp-admin it'll download wp-login.php instead of actually rendering it?

Any ideas of what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have PHP installed (or working) on the server hosting blog.figurella.com.do, so the server is treating *.php files as unknowns and serving them as downloads.

Comment: that can't be because blog.figurella.com.do is a PHP website and it's showing up just fine.

Comment: Well, it's not seeing .php files as php. Have you spoken to your host? Something is badly configured.